# Can no longer add/remove metadata components via Eclipse IDE

Tags: force.com, metadata, eclipse

Recently Eclipse stopped picking up any new metadata components from the server. Via the Salesforce UI I am able to see new classes and VisualForce pages, but when I go to "add/remove metadata components" and hit the refresh button, these new components don't show up.

Worth noting is that I can still save, refresh, etc. all of the files currently checked out in my project, as well as add/remove any metadata components that were there before - I just can't get any new ones from the server.

When it was working in the past, I would click "refresh":

[image: refresh]

It would usually freeze up for a minute or two while it grabbed data from Salesforce, then show me a dialog indicating that certain component types are not supported:

[image: dialog]

Now, when I hit refresh the dialog opens almost immediately and none of the new components are available for selection - this tells me that for some reason there is no communication happening between Eclipse and the server.

Has anyone experienced this before? I haven't changed any settings that I am aware of, and the connection to Salesforce is otherwise unaffected.

I did manually edit package.xml somewhat recently, but I am fairly certain this was working properly after that.

Thanks in advance - let me know if I can make this any more clear.

Comment: Try to create a new project and see if you can see missing meta data in project. It happened to me as well and I always create a new project and copy existing project xml file to new project. I think something wrong in Eclipse cache.

Comment: Why don't you add your components to package.xml and refresh, sometimes it takes time to refresh the metadata components window, however whatever you have added via the metadata components window creates a new tag in package.xml, so you can edit/include your new components by adding package.xml

Comment: FWIW, in some orgs, I've seen this error message when creating new projects from the very start, but haven't had the problem of not being able to update the metadata. I wasn't impacted by what couldn't be retrieved initially and think it's a bug in the API35 IDE plugin for Eclipse IDE. In the past, these kinds of errors were often related to the version of the Java JRE you were using. Check to see if using latest for your OS & consider taking a step back if you are.

Comment: @SLman thanks for the suggestion, this did the trick. It would be frustrating to have to do this often so hopefully this doesn't occur again. If you'd like to post this as an answer I can select it as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy from my comments:
Try to create a new project and see if you can see missing meta data in project. It happened to me as well and I always create a new project and copy existing project xml file to new project. I think something wrong in Eclipse cache.

Comment: Do you know a way of clearing the cache? Even when creating new projects from scratch, I'm having similar problem where not all of the metadata is collected. Appears to me to be a java problem from looking at the logs, but updating the jdk & jre hasn't solved it for me. Get a message about the path not being found.